# 2003 Domain Functional Level -- Do I need to run adprep.exe to trust a 2012 DFL?

Tags: windows-server-2012, domain-controller, windows-server-2003-r2, active-directory

My company is still using Windows Server 2003 for the Domain Controllers, with DFL (and FFL) already raised to 2003 DFL/FFL.

Now, we need to trust the domain of our new subsidiary. Their domain is using Windows Server 2012 (not R2) for their DCs, with 2012 DFL/FFL.

Do we need to run adprep.exe from 2012 on our 2003 DCs to establish the trust relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you do but I am basing that on the previous establishing of Trust between 2003 and 2008/R2 domains.  Looking at the [Checklist on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770907.aspx) there is no mention of ADPrep being required.